# Creating a line that contours a mesh with three.js

Tags: three.js, line, mesh, contour

I have a simple square mesh that has height values derived from a data set of ground elevation values. Is there a way given two (or more) X,Y coordinates to draw a line that will follow the surface of the mesh (i.e. to represent a road on the ground)?

I've been following [these blog posts](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/10/terrain-building-with-threejs-part-1.html) to create a terrain mesh, and I'd like to add a series of lines (the points of which don't have height values) to the mesh, without drawing them on the texture.

Is there a way to do this without having to index the height values for each point, which are in a different X/Y scale?